# I get errors tring to install django cripsy forms

Tags: django-forms

When I try to install django cripsy forms via the command:

'pip install django-cripsy-forms'

but I keep getting the following errors:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-cripsy-forms (from versions: none) and
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-cripsy-forms.

Please can anyone help me fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I think there may be a spelling error. "cripsy" should be "crispy"

Comment: Thanks so much, it was actually spelling error.